# pandas merge and group concat

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do something like GROUP BY / GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL using pandas. Let's say I have:

table_a

```
col_a col_b
A     1
B     2
C     2
```

table_b

```
col_a col_c
A     VALUE_1
A     VALUE_2
B     VALUE_3
C     VALUE_4
```

I want a new table_c as follow:

```
col_a col_b col_c
A     1      VALUE_1, VALUE_2
B     2      VALUE_3
C     2      VALUE_4
```

I've been using *pd.merge* but I cannot find a way to do the concatenation and avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or using `agg` after `merge`

```
df1.merge(df2).groupby('col_a',as_index=False).agg({'col_b':'first','col_c':','.join})
Out[46]: 
  col_a  col_b            col_c
0     A      1  VALUE_1,VALUE_2
1     B      2          VALUE_3
2     C      2          VALUE_4
```

Comment: I'll select this just because I like the fact that I can use 'first'

Answer (score 5):

`groupby` before `merge`, ensuring `'col_a'` is unique in the right Frame:

```
df1.merge(df2.groupby('col_a').col_c.apply(', '.join).reset_index())

  col_a  col_b             col_c
0     A      1  VALUE_1, VALUE_2
1     B      2           VALUE_3
2     C      2           VALUE_4
```